# Which is more efficient - hitting my db or doing an extra web crawl and hitting an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I have a web crawler that looks for specific information I want and returns it. This is run daily.

The issue is that my crawler has to do two things.

1. Get the link it has to crawl.
2. Crawl said link and push stuff to the db.

The issue with #1 is, there are 700+ links in total. These links don't change VERY frequently - maybe once a month?

So one option is just to do a separate crawl for the 'list of links', once a month, and dump the links into the db.

Then, have the crawler do a db hit for each of those 700 links every day.

Or, I can just have a nested crawl within my crawler - where every single time the crawler is run (daily), it updates this list of 700 URLs and stores it in an array and pulls it from this array to do crawl each link.

Which is more efficient and be less taxing on Heroku - or whichever host?

Comment: Wait, what doesn't change often: the content on the links to crawl, or the set of links that you have to crawl? I'm not sure I understand your question or alternatives.

Comment: Set of links to crawl doesn't change much.

Comment: So your question is: which is "better", to fetch 700 rows from a local database or to perform an HTTP request that returns those 700 hits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on how you measure "efficiency" and "taxing", but the local database hit is almost certain to be faster and "better" than an HTTP request + parsing an HTML(?) response for the links.

Further, not that it likely matters, but (assuming your database and adapter support it) you can begin to iterate through the DB request results and process them without waiting for or fetching the entire set into memory.

Network latency and resources are going to be much worse than poking at a DB that is already sitting there, running, and designed to be queried efficiently and quickly.

However: once per day? Is there a good reason to spend any energy optimizing this task?

Comment: Interesting, can you tell me more about paging through the db request results? I am using PostgreSQL, ActiveRecord and Heroku in production.

Comment: 700 links don't even need paging :)

Comment: @marcamillion I was thinking of [`Sequel::Dataset#each`](http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/classes/Sequel/Dataset.html#method-i-each) which, _"Iterates over the records in the dataset as they are yielded from the database adapter"_ as opposed to something like `my_dataset.all.each` which would require the entire set to be fetched and loaded into a Ruby array before iteration can begin.

Comment: ActiveRecord has [`find_each`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Batches.html#method-i-find_each). More in [the guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#retrieving-multiple-objects-in-batches) as well. But as Sergio said, 700 records isn't that many (unless they contain a lot of data each).

Comment: Interesting. I will look into those. I see what you mean Phrogz.

Comment: @AndrewMarshall you may be right. Maybe 700 records is nothing :)

Comment: @Sergio-tulentsev See my comment about 700 records =)

Comment: @marcamillion: the one right above? 700 records a second is *something*, 700 records a day - not worth even thinking about :)